# Input Array in C and check for same values

Tags: c, arrays, loops, sorting

how I can input an array of integers and check if 2 pairs of values are equal and I also want to remove the duplicated to have only 1 same value in array?
I want to print the final result of the array without the duplicated values in it.
I have something like this in mind:

```
int a[SIZE], i;
 printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", SIZE);
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  scanf_s("%d", a[i]);
 if(i>=1){
  if(a[i-1]==a[i]){
  a[i-1]==a[i];
  printf("%d", a[i-1]);
 }
}
```

this result gives me what I need but not completely. 
can you assist with this?

Comment: `if(i==1)`...why?

Comment: because i want to compare 2 values each time, 1-2,2-3,3-4 etc..by this way i can compare 1st value which I entered and continue then. if I wont do this, i dont have first value to compare with second value. the other option i can do this is only if i store the first number in some value.

Comment: you are comparing every number with `1` i.e `i == 1` ??

Comment: One way is to input the array, sort it, check for duplicates, remove the duplicates, repeat until required number of distinct values have been input.     Another way is, each time a value (after the first) is read, to check if it is already in the array, and discard it if it is.   I leave writing code for either approach as an exercise.

Comment: @ThiruShetty no, my bad there i wanted to do this i>=1, when iterator is larger/equals to 1(means we are on 2nd element in array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   int arr[20], i, j, k, size;
   printf("\nEnter array size:");
   scanf("%d", &size);
   printf("\nEnter Numbers:");
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   printf("\nList of Unique Numbers:");
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < size;) {
         if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
            for (k = j; k < size; k++) {
               arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
            }
            size--;
         } else
            j++;
      }
   }
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
   }
}
```

## Explanation

After inputting, we start from the first element.  Then within that for loop, we have another for loop to check elements after that element.  If there is a duplicate, I remove it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, will check! Just wonder, does it effect efficiency if so much loops are used? I'm just started with studying C so sorry if i might ask some stupid questions =/

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the most efficient one(at least that i know of)